# Cross-domain tracking between ga.js and analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

The website is running on two domains, a.com and b.com. Both domains are running ga.js and bi-directional cross-domain tracking is in place. We would like start upgrading to Universal Analytics and keep using the same UA-code we are using now.

The problem is that we are only able to upgrade a.com to Universal Analytics at this moment. The other domain, b.com, will continue running ga.js with the current implementation and we are not able to make any changes to its tracking code.

Is there a way to make cross-domain tracking work between a.com and b.com when a.com is running analytics.js and b.com ga.js? If yes, what possible issues should I keep in mind?

[This doc item](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#cross-domain) seems quite clear that both a.com and b.com need to run analytics.js for cross-domain tracking to work, but [this item about history import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#dont-finish) made me hope there might be a work-around:

> Customizing ga.js history import
>   Additional configuration may be required in cases where cookie information needs to be transferred from a Universal Analytics cookie to classic Google Analytics cookies set by ga.js, such as with larger websites that have not completely retagged with analytics.js and have both tracking codes present for some period of time.

I don't quite understand what the latter says, though.

Comment: Olss, so I guess you are using 2 different Analytics properties, correct?

Comment: @PetrHavlík: We are currently reporting to only one analytics property from two different domains. Both domains are using classic ga. The other domain is running the e-commerce part of the site. We would like to keep using the same property in the future as well.